# Unknown migration for 'djcelery:0001_initial' when migrating Django application using South

Tags: django, django-south, django-migrations, djcelery

I got following error when migrating my Django application using South.

```
    from django.db import models, migrations
    ImportError: cannot import name migrations
```

I use `Django==1.5.7` `django-celery==3.2.1` and  `South==1.0.1` in my application.

This is the log,

```
    UnknownMigration: Migration 'djcelery:0001_initial' probably doesn't exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 310, in migration
    migration = __import__(full_name, {}, {}, ['Migration'])
  File "/env/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_celery-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/djcelery/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db import models, migrations
ImportError: cannot import name migrations
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651716/from-django-db-import-models-migrations-importerror-cannot-import-name-migrati) doesn't solve my question because I'm using South to migrate here and seems it is related to django-celery.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651716/from-django-db-import-models-migrations-importerror-cannot-import-name-migrati

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from django.db import models, migrations ImportError: cannot import name migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651716/from-django-db-import-models-migrations-importerror-cannot-import-name-migrati)

Comment: @Bijoy This is about using South to migrate in Django and I think it is related to djcelery.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  Here I'm using South to migrate.